# Saving a discord emoji in the database DISCORD:JS

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

I'm making a reaction bot, and I am currently making the add emoji command. The command need the message id, the role its going to give the user and the emoji its going to display. But I don't know how to turn the emoji into a sort of id? I don't know how to turn the mention of a role into an id, can anyone help me with that?

```
let ARGmsgId = args[0];
let ARGemoji = args[1]; // USER IS GOING TO ENTER IN AN EMOJI - I WANT TO TURN IT INTO A SORT OF EMOJI ID THAT I CAN STORE IN THE DATABASE
let ARGrole = args[2]; //USER IS GOING TO MENTION A ROLE - I WANT TO TURN IT INTO A ROLE ID THAT I CAN STORE IN THE DATABASE
```

These are my current arguments

Comment: aren't emojis is discord.js retrieve as string? (:example:)
there can not be two emojis with the same name at the same server. why not use attribute to store the emojis names?
also, when you want to get them back to emoji format, discord will automatically serialize the string back to emoji in the GUI

Comment: Could you give an example? I'm quite lost ahah @avivgood2

Answer (score 0):

A custom emoji will be parsed in the format of `<a:name:id>` (with the `a` if it's undefined). A unicode emoji will be parsed as `:name:`. Either way, you can use `String#match()` to extract the ID.

```js
const emoji = args[1].match(/<a?:(.+):\d{17,18}>|:(.+):/)[1];

// regex breakdown:

// a? - question mark after any character means optional
// () - this will capture the name for later recognition
// .+ - one or more of any character (the name)
// \d{17,18} - the 17-18 digit ID
// | - or operator- either use the format for the custom emoji or the unicode
```

To get a mentioned role, use `MessageMentions#roles` and `Collection#first`

```js
const role = message.mentions.roles.first();
```

Comment: Regex seems to be wrong, it returns null :/

Comment: [I can assure you the regex is correct](https://jsfiddle.net/p7mh8td3/)